# Can you click on a button and it add text to a form field?

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a system to allow users to login to a page using clickable images as opposed to standard text based passwords. Each click on an image will represent a short string and this will build a password.

I have created a registration form and the clickable images. What I am unable to do is to create way of making the password. What I am trying to do is each click on an image will add text to the password field of the form. This will build up with each image clicked and then be hashed and sent to the database.

Can you use innerhtml or similar to add text to a form field? This is the way I had planned to do it but I have had not success as yet. Any pointers in the right direction would be great.

```js
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", onClickFunc);

function onClickFunc(e) {

  let ele = document.getElementById('pword');
  ele.textContent = 'A1b2';
  alert("Function finished!");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<label>
  password 
  <input id="pword"  type="password" class="field" placeholder="password" 
       name="pword" required>
</label>
<div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div class="cellcontainer">
    <div class="grid">

      <div class="cell" id="one">
        <i class="fas fa-futbol "></i>
        </button>
```

Comment: You have to modify the `.value` property of the `<input>` element.

Comment: Please update the incomplete snippet I made you to a [mcve]

Comment: You should change ```ele.textContent = 'A1b2';``` to ```ele.value = 'A1b2';```
Inputs have value attribute and to set it using js, you should use ```.value```

Comment: your html is invalid

Comment: Thanks guys. I actually thought I tried ele.value earlier. Possibly had an error somewhere else in the .js that prevented it from working.